# jQuery :contains Selector if else statement

Tags: jquery, selector, contains, if-statement

I have a results page that show users how they scored on a webform. I'm trying to display different messages based on their answer.

I've set up a basic alert to show what the user has selected.

```
var q1 = $('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1').text();
alert(q1);

if ($('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1:contains("A. Yes")')) {
    $('.results-wrapper').hide();
    $('.results').append('<div class="popup">User Selected A. Yes, for the first answer.</div>');
}
else if ($('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1:contains("B. No")')) {
    $('.results-wrapper').hide();
    $('.results').append('<div class="popup">User Selected B. No, for the first answer.</div>');
}
else if ($('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1:contains("C. I do not know")')) {
   $('.results-wrapper').hide();
   $('.results').append('<div class="popup">User Selected C. I do not know, for the first answer.</div>');  
}
else {
   alert('something went wrong');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hr6Lj/10/

Comment: So what's the problem/question?

Comment: Why are you using selectors this way?  Couldn't you fetch `$('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1')` and then test it's contents via `html()`?

Comment: @JasonSperske Why would you test the string contents of the element instead of just testing if the element exists? that seems like a much more involved way of doing it when he can just add `.length` to his current code.

Comment: @KevinB, I guess it feels like an overuse of Sizzle of me, maybe it is a reasonable use, I've posted my approach

Comment: @JasonSperske It's definitely more complex that it needs to be, i would have probably fixed it farther up the chain, keeping the answers in an object rather than the html.

Comment: @j08691 the problem is that the first if statement is fired when it isn't supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will always be true because objects are always true.

```
if ($('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1:contains("A. Yes")'))
```

What you want is to know if any elements are selected.

```
if ($('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1:contains("A. Yes")').length)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it (using jQuery's [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) funciton) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/Hr6Lj/12/))

```
<div class="results">
    <div class="results-wrapper">
        <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-display" id="webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1"
        data-answer="C">C. I do not know</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  var updateAnswer = function (question) {
    var answer = question.data('answer');
    if (answer === 'A') {
      $('.results-wrapper').hide();
      $('.results').append('<div class="popup">User Selected A. Yes, for the first answer.</div>');
    } else if (answer === 'B') {
      $('.results-wrapper').hide();
      $('.results').append('<div class="popup">User Selected B. No, for the first answer.</div>');
    } else if (answer === 'C') {
      $('.results-wrapper').hide();
      $('.results').append('<div class="popup">User Selected C. I do not know, for the first answer.</div>');
    } else {
      alert('something went wrong');
    }
  }
  updateAnswer($('#webform-component-fieldset-1--question-1'));
</script>
```

Comment: Made it (slightly) more general